# How can I await a variable

Tags: asynchronous, flutter, dart, async-await, reactive-programming

Is it possible to use a `Future` to `await` a change of value of a simple variable in Dart?

In my case, I have a singleton method that, upon the first call, creates and opens a database. This method is being called from multiple places in my app, and I need a way for the second, third, etc. calls to wait until the first call has created and opened the database.

```
class DB{
    static Database _db;

    static Future<Database> instance() async {
        if( _db == null ){
            print('Creating/opening database');
            _db = await createOrOpenDatabase();
        }            

        return _db;
    }
}

// Somewhere in the app
await DB.instance().doSomething();


// Meanwhile, somewhere else in the app
await DB.instance().doSomethingElse();
```

This results in

```
Creating/opening database
Creating/opening database
```

One way to solve this would be to add some variable that indicates that the database is currently being created and/or opened:

```
class DB{
    static Database _db;
    static bool _openingDb;

    static Database instance() async {
        if( _openingDb )
            // Wait until _openingDb becomes false

        if( _db == null ){
            _openingDb = true;
            print('Creating/opening database');
            _db = await createOrOpenDatabase();
            _openingDb = false;
        }            

        return _db;
    }
}
```

But just how do I wait for the value of `_openingDb` to change? It seems like I'm missing something obvious here...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out that I can use a [Completer](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.4.0/dart-async/Completer-class.html) to accomplish what I wanted.

```
class DB {
    static Database _db;
    static Completer _dbOpenCompleter;

    static Future<Database> instance() async {
        if( _dbOpenCompleter != null && !_dbOpenCompleter.isCompleted ) {
            print('Awaiting database creation');        
            await _dbOpenCompleter.future;
        }

        if( _db == null ) {
            _dbOpenCompleter = Completer();
            try {
                print('Creating/opening database');            
                _db = await openOrCreateDatabase();
            }
            finally{
                _dbOpenCompleter.complete();
            }
        }

        return _db;
    }
}
```

Now the same calls as in the original question result in the following output:

```
Creating/opening database
Awaiting database creation
```